# Oracle and Nodejs - can't bind parameters in SQL statement

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

Hi I have the following statement that I execute using [node-oracle](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#inbind)

```
await connection.execute(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%And%'`)
```

But now I want to bind a parameter instead of using a hard coded value

```
const queryText = 'And';
await connection.execute(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%:queryText%'`, {queryText});
```

it throws `Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

What is the correct way of binding a parameter here, since the documentation doesn't cover this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
const queryText = 'And';
await connection.execute(

"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE :queryText", 

{

queryText: { dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: '%'+ queryText +'%', type: oracledb.STRING }

});
```

Comment: Same error: Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%' || :queryText || '%'
```

Comment: It throws Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: @GeorgianStan: it is very unlikely that this query would raise that error. There are no partentheses in the query to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
let queryText = "John"
let sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE :queryText"
let binds = {queryTarget: {dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: queryText, type: oracledb.STRING}}

let result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options)
```

Do not add '%' like the other people suggested.

Comment: The '%' are needed to do pattern matching.   But they are not needed otherwise.